# How to schedule the start and stop of a Windows service?

Tags: .net, windows-services, cron

I've a .NET windows service that should start at 7:00 and stop at 23:00 each day, running continuously in background.

While I can code the service so that it sleep between 23 and 7, I would prefer a system configuration (something like [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) in unix).

How can I do this on Windows 7?

Note that, if system boot up after 7:00, the service should start immediatly.

Comment: Not sure I'd bother with this route unless I had a number of services I needed this sort of behavior and I wanted some way of externally managing their configurations

Comment: Actually, I have 3 services that should start and stop at the same times.

Comment: Scheduling service if you want to seem them in services.msc, or the ServiceHost and some sort of custom applet to manange it if you don't then.

Answer (score 7):

1- Create a batch file such as starter.bat and type NET START "SERVICE NAME"

2- Create a Task in Task Scheduler for 7:00 a.m that run batch file every day and remember to check *Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed* in Settings tab so it will start even if system boot up after 7 a.m.

Repeat those steps for stoper.bat include NET STOP "SERVICE NAME" for 23:00 p.m

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Windows task scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) for this task or a [schedule task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task).

Also Windows [AT command is very similar to Cron in Unix](http://ss64.com/nt/at.html)

> "The AT command schedules commands and programs to run on a computer
>   at a specified time and date. The Schedule service must be running to
>   use the AT command."

Answer (score 0):

Or you could write another service, let's call it guard which runs always und starts the other service depending on a config file for example.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you need another service to manage the scheduling of the services.
Write a service, that hosts service like thingies. The host deals with starting and stopping, even restarting in the event of a crash. You can even get clever and get it to look up with "services" to load an run, and applet to see what's going on and tweak the schedule , register and unregister services with the host.

An approach anyway.

Answer (score 0):

AT command gets deprecated at some point. this works server 2012 windows 10.

schtasks /create /tn "StartWrapper" /tr "NET START 'Name of Service'" /sc daily /st 23:05 /RL HIGHEST

You have to play with the quotes to escape the command correctly.